# When does code in .aspx code executed

Tags: .net

I am trying to find out which event i should put my code that would normally be placed in .aspx. To be precise:
Normally i can write something like

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="lst1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

to populate my dropdownlist.

But i want this list to populate in my code behind class. I am trying to figure out which event like "On_Init", "On_Prerender" is best place to put the code so that it has same effect as above.

I am trying to use following code in my code behind class:

```
   for int i=5; i<=9; i++
    {
       lst1.items.add(i) 
    }
```

Thanks
CSS

Comment: **[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx)**: Live it, Learn It, Breathe It

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best place is on Page_Load method! But it depends most from your application architecture!

Comment: My Apologies, I should have clarified my answer better. When i put my code in .aspx i am getting different behavior than when i put the page_load event. I am working with web parts. The dropdown stores the user preference. when the dropdown is populated in .aspx the user selection in edit mode of webpart is correctly shown during display mode but when the same dropdown is populated in page_load method, the dropdown always shows the default value.

Answer (score 2):

You can put it in either `Page_Load` or `Page_Init` or even `Page_PreRender`.

Note: if you add it to `Load` or `PreRender`, you'll want to wrap it inside a check for a postback (as necessary) so that you don't add items to the control that are already there.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    for (int i = 5; i <= 9; i++)
         lst1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: The need for an "IsPostBack" check depends on whether or not viewstate is enabled for the control

Comment: And assuming you want a selected value to stick, you'll want viewstate enabled!

Comment: I have tried that but in the scenario I am working on, it did not work. I am working with web parts. The dropdown is used for storing user preference (no of items he/she would like to see). Everything staying same in my code, if i use the code in .aspx, the dropdown shows correct values(as selected by user in edit mode) in displaymode but if i populate the same dropdown in page_load or page_init or page_prerender, the dropdown always ends up showing default value in display mode..

Comment: @CSC, I would advise you to add that information *to the question.* Describe your UI (web parts), your actual problem, what you've tried, and the results you've seen. Based on the *text of the question*, the answers are sufficient. If you want better answers, write a better question!

Answer (score 0):

`Page_Load` is where you want to put this.

Your code has bad syntax:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 5; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        lst1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding controls to a page then place it in Page_Load

If you are populating an already existing asp:DropDownList then populate the control in `lst1_Load`

don't use Page_Load as a catch-all